# Cannot use RX Android Observable.zip operator

Tags: android, rx-android

I am using rx-android zip operator to merge two retrofit calls.

Previously the code was like  this:

```
  affinityService.rewardsStatusChanges()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .compose(this.<RewardsStatus>bindToLifecycle())
            .subscribe(new Action1<RewardsStatus>() {
                @Override
                public void call(RewardsStatus rewardsStatus) {
                    onRewardStatus(rewardsStatus);
                }
            });

    affinityService.affinityStatusChanges()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .compose(this.<AffinityStatus>bindToLifecycle())
            .subscribe(new Action1<AffinityStatus>() {
                @Override
                public void call(AffinityStatus affinityStatus) {
                    onAffinityStatus(affinityStatus);
                }
            });
```

**rewardsStatusChanges() and affinityStatusChanges() are two retrofit calls.**

Now I need to merge them.

What I have tried:

```
affinityService.rewardsStatusChanges()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .compose(this.<RewardsStatus>bindToLifecycle())
                .flatMap(new Func1<RewardsStatus, Observable<RewardsStatus>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<RewardsStatus> call(RewardsStatus rewardsStatus) {
                        return Observable.just(rewardsStatus);
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(new Func1<RewardsStatus, Observable<RewardsStatus>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<RewardsStatus> call(RewardsStatus rewardsStatus) {
                        return Observable.zip(Observable.just(rewardsStatus),
                        affinityService.affinityStatusChanges(),new Func2<RewardsStatus, AffinityStatus, RewardsStatus>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public RewardsStatus call(RewardsStatus rewardsStatus, AffinityStatus affinityStatus) {
                                        onAffinityAndRewardsMerged(rewardsStatus,affinityStatus);
                                        return null;
                                    }

                        });
                    }
                });
```

But unfortunately the above codebase is not working.
Any idea how to do this.

I am using:

```
RX_ANDROID_VERSION=1.0.1
RX_JAVA_VERSION=1.0.14
```

Comment: Isnt zip operator supposed to be used like - Observable.zip(firstObservable, secondObservable) - guess you dont need to do all that flatMapping

Comment: Thank you for your response.The first two arguments for the zip opertaor that I have writtten are observables.

Comment: Yes but I mean that you can start directly - Observable.zip(affinityService.rewardsStatusChanges(), affinityService.affinityStatusChanges()){... zip function ...}. subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(... consumer ....)

Comment: Ok,will try and surely let you know

Comment: Tried:  Observable.zip(affinityService.rewardsStatusChanges(),
                affinityService.affinityStatusChanges(),new Func2<RewardsStatus, AffinityStatus, RewardsStatus>() {
                    @Override
                    public RewardsStatus call(RewardsStatus rewardsStatus, AffinityStatus affinityStatus) {
                        onAffinityAndRewardsMerged(rewardsStatus,affinityStatus);
                        return null;
                    }

                }); Still not working

Comment: looks good, however I think you want to return like a pair object  - instead of null - that will contain your two models bundled from the zip function. That way you will get this pair object in your consumer and there you can do whatever you need with that result

Comment: I missed the .subscribe () at last.It is working now.Thank you.Please post this as an answer so that I can accept

Comment: Observable.zip(affinityService.rewardsStatusChanges(),
                affinityService.affinityStatusChanges(),new Func2<RewardsStatus, AffinityStatus, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void call(RewardsStatus rewardsStatus, AffinityStatus affinityStatus) {
                        onAffinityAndRewardsMerged(rewardsStatus,affinityStatus);
                        return null;
                    }

                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe();

Comment: Returning null doesnt matter as my aim is to execute the method onAffinityAndRewardsMerged(rewardsStatus,affinityStatus); which is accomplished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

posting as you wished, however with that return null in the anonymous function you will get null in your consumer, so I think returning like `Pair<RewardsStatus,AffinityStatus>` would be nicer, and do that result processing in the consumer.

```
 Observable.zip(affinityService.rewardsStatusChanges(), affinityService.affinityStatusChanges(),
            object : Func2<RewardsStatus, AffinityStatus, RewardsStatus>() {
                fun call(rewardsStatus: RewardsStatus, affinityStatus: AffinityStatus): RewardsStatus? {
                    onAffinityAndRewardsMerged(rewardsStatus, affinityStatus)
                    return null
                }
            })
```

Comment: This is working.I think it is in javascript ,the above one?

Comment: its kotlin, i needed to format it so I pasted in quickly in my project and got it converted to Kotlin

Comment: Oh..Actually till now I have not worked with Kotlin.Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @estn anyway to include compose method call with this one?

Comment: The zip function returns new observable, so you can just keep chaining - add compose after that zip

Comment: yes tried it but not working as two different observables are there

Comment: Actually when I am trying to update views from the onAffinityAndRewardsMerged(rewardsStatus, affinityStatus) method it is giving me an error: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: Two different obsevables? Seems weird, as far as i know zip returns one observable.  As far as threading - everything that is before  subscribeOn(schedulers.io) is happenning on that thread, that means your zip function is executed on that io thread, it will be better if you do it as I suggested originally - do that processing in the subscribe consumer, not sort of like a "side effect"

Comment: Got it i solved it by using .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() on each observables :

Comment: Note that order of these operators matters. first you zip observables, which retuns new observable, which you can then compose, then you do subscribeOn(io) - this means that zip and compose will be executed on io thread. Then you do observe on which means everything below this will happen on that thread - in your case its UI and then you subscribe - because its below that observeOn(android) that will happen on androids main thread

Comment: Observable.zip(affinityService.rewardsStatusChanges().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()),                affinityService.affinityStatusChanges().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()),new Func2<RewardsStatus, AffinityStatus, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void call(RewardsStatus rewardsStatus, AffinityStatus affinityStatus) {
                   
                    }

                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe();

Comment: Just another thing: whnever I am changing something to affinity,this zip operator is not getting called.I mean the zip operator must listen any changes in rewards or affinity class.But it is not happening in my case.Any idea?

Comment: It is happening when I write rewards and affinity individually,like the first part of my question

Comment: You mean that there is only one item in that observable stream ? Well if its retrofit call then its designed that way, its only one item unless you say that you want to repreat it or whatsoever. Take a look at this video if its still confusing : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdmkXL7XikQ

Comment: My zip operator is taking two items,rewards and affinity.But is not listening to any changes that I am doing in the affinity object.

Comment: This retrofit observable fires off one network request by design. But observables can contain more than one items, thats why it might be confusing and I guess returning Single instead of Observable from retrofit is more clear

Comment: Sorry I dont know what you mean. You have two observables that each when subscribed fire off one network call. Now what the zip does, is that it will combine results of each observable and transform it to another item and return another observable of that type - which is returned from that zip function, then you can do another stuff with that observable, like compose, map, and so on

Comment: Yes I agree.But the affinitystatus is a observable,So if I change something to the affinitystatusfrom some other part of the app,the affinity status should also reflect that change(as it is an observable) and merge it into the zip operator.Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I dont think you understand it, Observable on its own doesnt have this kind of behavior, yes you can achieve this kind of behavior but not right out the box just because its an Observable